# facing problem to create camera relative movement in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started study on this from past few weeks. I
I try to create character movement script in unity on 3d model, I want player follow camera continuously but it only follows when I release the forward button and again pressed it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class NewAnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Camera variable
    Transform cameraTransform;

    //Declare reference variable
    PlayerInput playerInput;
    CharacterController characterController;
    Animator animator;

    //variable to store optimized setter/getter parameter Id's
    int isRunningHash;
    int isSprintingHash;

    //variable to store current input values
    Vector2 currentMovementInput;
    Vector3 currentMovement;
    Vector3 currentRunMovement;
    Vector3 appliedMovement;
    bool isMovementPressed;
    bool isRunPressed;
    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    float RunSpeed = 3.0f;
    float rotationFactorPerFrame = 15.0f;


    //gravity variable
    float GroundedGravity = -0.05f;
    float Gravity = -9.81f;

    //Jumping variables
    bool isJumpPressed = false;
    bool isJumping = false;
    float initialJumpingVelocity;
    float maxJumpHight = 2.0f;
    float maxJumpTime = 0.75f;
    int isJumpingHash;
    bool isJumpAnimating = false;

    //Attack Variable
    bool isAttackPressed = false;
    bool isAttacking = false;
    int isAttackingHash;
    int attackCount = 0;
    float attackCountSpeed = 1f;
    bool coolDown;
    bool cooldownStart;
    bool stopMove = false; 
    bool isAttackAnimate= true;
    bool Attack_2Animate = true;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        
        playerInput = new PlayerInput();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        isRunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isRunning");
        isSprintingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isSprinting");
        isJumpingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isJumping");
        isAttackingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isAttack");
        
        playerInput.Movement.Move.started += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.Movement.Move.canceled += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.Movement.Move.performed += onMovementInput;
        playerInput.Movement.Run.started += onRun; 
        playerInput.Movement.Run.canceled += onRun;
        playerInput.Movement.Jump.started += onJump;
        playerInput.Movement.Jump.canceled += onJump;
        playerInput.Movement.Attack.started += onAttack;
        playerInput.Movement.Attack.canceled += onAttack;   

        setJumpVariable();

    }
    // Start()
    // {

    // }


    void handleAttacking()
    {
       if(isAttackPressed && !isAttacking && attackCount%2 == 0 && !isJumpAnimating)
       {
        stopMove = true;
        isAttackAnimate =false;
        Attack_2Animate = true;
        attackCount++;
        isAttacking = true;
        animator.SetBool(isAttackingHash, true);
        //Debug.Log(attackCount);
       }
       else if( attackCount> 2 && cooldownStart && !isJumpAnimating)
       {
        stopMove = true;
        isAttackAnimate =true;
        Attack_2Animate =false;
        //Debug.Log(attackCount);
        //isAttack_2Animating = true;
        animator.SetBool(isAttackingHash, true);
        animator.SetBool("isAttack_2", true);
       }
        if(!cooldownStart )
        {
            //isAttack_2Animating = false;
            animator.SetBool("isAttack_2", false);
        }
       if(!isAttackPressed && isAttacking && !cooldownStart)
       {
        attackCount++;
        //Debug.Log(attackCount);
        isAttacking =false;
        animator.SetBool(isAttackingHash, false);
        cooldownStart =true;
       }
        
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        stopMove = false;
        if(Attack_2Animate == true)
        {
            isAttackAnimate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isAttackAnimate =false;
        }
        Debug.Log(isAttackAnimate);
    }
    public void Unlock2()
    {
        stopMove = false;
        if(isAttackAnimate == false)
        {
            Attack_2Animate =true;
            isAttackAnimate =true;
        }
        else
        {
            Attack_2Animate = false;
        }
    }

    void onAttack(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isAttackPressed = context.ReadValueAsButton();
        //Debug.Log(isAttackPressed);
    }


    void setJumpVariable()
    {
        float timeToApex = maxJumpTime /2;
        Gravity = (-2 * maxJumpHight / Mathf.Pow(timeToApex ,2));
        initialJumpingVelocity = (2 * maxJumpHight) / timeToApex;
    }

    void handleJump()
    {
        if(!isJumping && characterController.isGrounded && isJumpPressed)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isJumpingHash, true);
            isJumpAnimating = true;
            isJumping = true;
            currentMovement.y = initialJumpingVelocity;
            appliedMovement.y = initialJumpingVelocity;
        }
        else if(isJumping && characterController.isGrounded && !isJumpPressed)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    void onJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isJumpPressed = context.ReadValueAsButton();
    }

    void handleGravity()
    {
        bool isFalling = currentMovement.y <= 0.0f || !isJumpPressed;
        float fallMultiplier = 2.0f;
        
        if(characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            if(isJumpAnimating)
            {
                animator.SetBool(isJumpingHash, false);
                isJumpAnimating = false;

            }
            currentMovement.y = GroundedGravity;
            appliedMovement.y = GroundedGravity;
        }
        else if(isFalling)
        {
            float previousYVelocity = currentMovement.y;
            currentMovement.y = currentMovement.y + (Gravity * fallMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);
            appliedMovement.y = Mathf.Max((previousYVelocity + currentMovement.y) * 0.5f, -20f);
        }
        else
        {
            float previousYVelocity = currentMovement.y;
            currentMovement.y = currentMovement.y + (Gravity * Time.deltaTime);
            appliedMovement.y = (previousYVelocity + currentMovement.y) * 0.5f;
        }
    }

    void onRun(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        isRunPressed = context.ReadValueAsButton();
    }

    void onMovementInput(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
            currentMovementInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            
    }
    void handleMovement()
    {
        currentMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x * moveSpeed;
        currentMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y * moveSpeed;
        currentRunMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x * RunSpeed;
        currentRunMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y * RunSpeed;
        isMovementPressed = currentMovementInput.x != 0 || currentMovementInput.y != 0;
        currentMovement = currentMovement.x * cameraTransform.right.normalized + currentMovement.z * cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
        currentRunMovement = currentRunMovement.x * cameraTransform.right.normalized + currentRunMovement.z * cameraTransform.forward.normalized;
    }
    
    
    
    void handleRotation()
    {
        Vector3 positionToLookAt;

        positionToLookAt.x = currentMovement.x;
        positionToLookAt.y = 0.0f;
        positionToLookAt.z = currentMovement.z;
        //current rotation of our Chararcter
        Quaternion currentRotation = transform.rotation;

        if(isMovementPressed )
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(positionToLookAt);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentRotation,targetRotation,rotationFactorPerFrame * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        
    }
    void handleAnimation()
    {
        //get Parameter values from animator
        bool isRunning = animator.GetBool(isRunningHash);
        bool isSprinting = animator.GetBool(isSprintingHash);

        if(isMovementPressed && !isRunning)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, true);
        }
        else if(!isMovementPressed && isRunning)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, false);
        }   
        if((isMovementPressed && isRunPressed) && !isSprinting)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isSprintingHash, true);
        } 
        else if((!isMovementPressed || !isRunPressed) && isSprinting)
        {
            animator.SetBool(isSprintingHash, false);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        handleAnimation();
        handleRotation();
        handleAttacking();
        handleMovement();
        if(cooldownStart)
        {
            attackCountSpeed = attackCountSpeed  + 1 * Time.deltaTime ; 
            //Debug.Log(attackCountSpeed);
        }
        if(attackCountSpeed > 2.0f)
        {
            cooldownStart = false;
            attackCountSpeed = 1f;
            attackCount = 0;
        }

   
        if(isRunPressed )
        {   
        appliedMovement.x = currentRunMovement.x;
        appliedMovement.z = currentRunMovement.z;
           
        }
        else
        {
        appliedMovement.x = currentMovement.x;
        appliedMovement.z = currentMovement.z; 
        }
        if(isAttackAnimate && Attack_2Animate && !stopMove)
        {
        characterController.Move(appliedMovement  * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        handleGravity();
        handleJump();

    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        playerInput.Movement.Enable();
    }
    void OnDisable()
    {
        playerInput.Movement.Disable();   
    }
}
```

I also try camera relative movement part cut from onMovementInput function and paste it in another function and call it in update function after applying this camera relative movement work properly but gravity and Jumping function not working.
I expect player will follow camera continuously and Jump and gravity also.
Character Controller Component and New Input System used in this script.